# Logistic regression to a decision tree

Tags: logistic, classification, cart

Having a regression model, how can I convert it into a decision tree?

I am curious about a formal/systematic way rather than a sampling-fitting approach that can work for arbitrary conversion of two black-box models.

A reasonable simplification is to consider a "crisp" activation, that is 0 and 1 only.

We may know the distribution of the input space and all inputs may be binary (either 0 and 1 coded or -1 and 1).

Comment: Can you please add an example?

Comment: Why do you think you should be able to do this?  The two methods are quite different and a tree can reveal things that you can't get in regression and vice versa.

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible. The motivation is to apply this trick iteratively to a mo

Comment: mlp so I have it in an interoperable form.